# Creating a closure inline

Tags: ios, closures, swift3

In WKWebView we have a method `evaluateJavaScript`. I have overridden this method to add custom code.

```
override open func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Swift.Void)? = nil) 
{
        let b:Bool? = true
        let error: Error? = NSError(domain: "com.My.Tests", code: 1000, userInfo: nil) as Error
        let completion = (b, error) -> Void
        evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString, completionHandler: completion)
}
```

How to pass the completion? It is throwing an error.

Comment: It depends on the version of Swift you are using.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: *"It is throwing an error."* - what error?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a real closure.

The signature expects something like

```
let completion = { (b, error) in print(b, error) }
```

The declared `b` and `error` variables are useless because `b` and `error` are returned from the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
override open func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Swift.Void)? = nil) 
{
        let b:Bool? = true
        let error: Error? = NSError(domain: "com.My.Tests", code: 1000, userInfo: nil) as Error
        evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString) { (result, error) in
          if error != nil {
            completionHandler?(nil, error)
          } else {
            completionHandler?(result, nil)
          }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `completion` is not a closure. It should be something like

```
let completion = { (b: Any?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    print("\(error)") 
}
```

I'm presuming that you want your `WKWebView` to act like some Javascript evaluation failed. If that's the case, you'd either:

```
override func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    evaluateJavaScript(javaScriptString) { b, error in
        completionHandler?(true, NSError(domain: "com.My.Tests", code: 1000))
    }
}
```

Or, if you didn't really need to evaluate the Javascript, but just *look* like a failure (e.g. stubbing it in a test):

```
override func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    completionHandler?(true, NSError(domain: "com.My.Tests", code: 1000))
}
```